# Limit $\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)}\right)^x$

Tags: calculus, limits

Can someone please explain to me how to solve this? According to my book the result should be $e^4$, however I cannot understand the proposed solution. Can someone please take the time to walk me through it?

$$f : \mathcal R \mapsto \mathbb R, f(x) = (x - 2)(x - 3)(x - 4)(x - 5)$$
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)}\right)^x$$

---

**Edit:** Partial solution.

I can get up to the following point. From here onwards however I do not know how to continue in order to get $e^4$. It appears to me that the result is $1^\infty = 1$ at this point (but that's not the case according to my book):

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\frac{x-1}{x-5}\right)^x$$

---

**Edit 2:** Solution given by my book.

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{4}{x-5}\right)^x$$
$$ = \lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\left(1+\frac{4}{x-5}\right)^\frac{x - 5}{4}\right)^{\frac{4}{x - 5}x}$$
$$ = e^{\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{4x}{x - 5}} = e^4$$

Comment: you probably mean $\lim (f(x+1)/f(x))^x$, if you want to get that answer

Comment: Yes, sorry for the mistake. :(

Comment: @Paul $1^{\infty}$ is an [indeterminate form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form).  You can't directly substitute to find its limit.

Comment: @Billare Ah, I suspected so, but Wolfram|Alpha told me otherwise so I assumed $1^\infty$ isn't indeterminate.

Comment: You want to rewrite the numerator as $(x - 5) + 4$, divide the top and bottom of the leftover fraction by $4$, and then substitute $u$ = $\frac{x-5}{4}$ to get the whole thing into the "classical limit" for $e$.

Comment: @Paul: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10490/why-is-1-infty-considered-to-be-an-indeterminate-form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are here at an "archetypic" experience you have to face when going into mathematics. It all starts with the search for
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bigl( 1+{1\over n} \Bigr)^n$$
(you may write $x$ instead of $n$). If the inner $n$ goes to $\infty$ first, the limit is $1$, and if the $n$ in the exponent goes to $\infty$ first, the limit is $\infty$. As a matter of fact (and this has to be proven the hard way) the true limit is a finite number, namely Euler's number $e\doteq 2.718$. Accepting this, it is easy to show that for any fixed $y>0$ one has
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\Bigl( 1+{y\over x} \Bigr)^x=e^y\ .$$
The $x-5$ in your denominator causes no trouble: Just adapt the exponent accordingly, and the extra factor with constant exponent $5$ will converge to $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  What do you get when you write the fraction $\frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)}$ just as a function of $x$ by substituting in $x+1$ in the numerator?

Added in response to the edit:  $\frac{x-1}{x-5}=1+\frac{4}{x-5}$, so you are looking for $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{4}{x-5}\right)^x.$$  Have you seen $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e?$$

Comment: The problem I'm facing isn't _that_ basic. I'll add some more details so people won't bother trying to explain the very basic things to me. :)

Comment: @Paul: Then you should show the work you have done, such as what you have for the function you are taking the limit of.  It will be easier to answer your question.

Comment: @Ross I edited my question.

Comment: @Paul Hint: Try converting $\frac{x-1}{x-5}$ into a partial fraction.

Comment: @Tyler You mean something like $1 + \frac{4}{n - 5}$? I still don't know how to continue.

Comment: @Paul: Now you are exactly at Ross's answer. Have you seen the e limit before?

Comment: @mixedmath and @Ross: Yes, I recognize that limit. But why does my book give $e^4$ as the result? I added the solution given by my book in my question.

Comment: Fundamentally, the -5 in the denominator doesn't matter when $x$ gets large and the 4 in the numerator becomes the exponent of $e$.  The book is getting into the form of the expression for $e$, then moving the limit into the exponential.