# Regarding limits and $1^\infty$

Tags: limits, infinity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is $1^{\infty}$ considered to be an indeterminate form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10490/why-is-1-infty-considered-to-be-an-indeterminate-form)

I have some questions about limits and the undefinability of $1^\infty$.

For example, is $\lim_{x\to\infty}1^x$ indefinite? Why is it not $1$? Or do mathematicians, when saying that $1^\infty$ is indefinite, actually refer to cases such as $lim_{x\to\infty} \left(1 + \frac{a}{x}\right)^x$ where even though at a first glace the result is $1$, this is actually a special case and it is equal to $e^a$?

Comment: Please see the reference.

Comment: @Chandru I'm going through their answers right now. :)

Comment: Sure, go through.

Answer (score 4):

When people say that $1^{\infty}$ is an indeterminate form, what they mean is that if $f(x)$ is a function such that $\lim_{x \to r} f(x) = 1$ and $g(x)$ is a function such that $\lim_{x \to r} g(x) = \infty$, the value of $\lim_{x \to r} f(x)^{g(x)}$ is not uniquely determined *in general.* It is determined in the special case that $f(x) = 1$, in which case the limit is obviously just $1$.

Comment: This is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

By itself, $1^{\infty}$ doesn't mean anything, except the implication that you had a quantity of the form $a^b$, and $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}a=1$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}b=\infty$.  Depending on how quickly and from what direction $a$ approaches 1, and how quickly $b$ approaches $\infty$, $a^b$ could approach any non-negative number, infinity, or nothing in particular at all.

Answer (score 1):

Look up [indeterminate forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form). It depends on how you interpret $1^{\infty}$

The indeterminate form $1^{\infty} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(n)^{g(n)}$ where $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(n) = 1$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} g(n) = \infty$

For instance, all of the following limits are of the form $1^{\infty}$, yet they all evaluate to different numbers

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 1^n = 1$$

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n = e$$

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{\log(n)} \right)^n = \infty$$

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(1 - \frac{1}{\log(n)} \right)^n = 0$$

It is a question of which one tends faster whether $f(n) \rightarrow 1$ or $g(n) \rightarrow \infty$.

When you get a finite number which is non-zero and not one as the limit, there is in some sense a balance between the rate at which $f(n) \rightarrow 1$ and $g(n) \rightarrow \infty$.

When you get infinity or zero as the limit, $g(n) \rightarrow \infty$ faster than $f(n) \rightarrow 1$.

When you get $1$ as the limit, $f(n) \rightarrow 1$ faster than $g(n) \rightarrow \infty$.