# Why is $\lim_{n \to \infty}1^n$ undefined?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is $1^{\infty}$ considered to be an indeterminate form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10490/why-is-1-infty-considered-to-be-an-indeterminate-form)

this is probably a very simple question for analysts, but i don't understand why the limit of the function
$ \lim_{n \to \infty}1^n$
does not exist.

Comment: It is defined. This isn't what people mean when they say that $1^{\infty}$ is an indeterminate form.

Comment: Just to be clear:  The term $1^n = 1$ for all $n$.  So, $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} 1^n = 1$.  However, if $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) = 1$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} g(n) = \infty$, then $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) ^{g(n)}$ is indeterminant.  This last fact is discussed at length in the link above.

Answer (score 7):

Let 
$f_1(n)=1^n.$
Then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}f_1(n)=1$.

So there is no problem in evaluating $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} 1^n$.

Let 
$f_2(n)=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n.$

Then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}f_2(n)=e$.

Thus the difficulties come when we raise to the $n$-th power something that is **approaching** $1$.

Here are a few more examples.

Let $f_3(n)=\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^n$. Then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} f_3(n)$ does not exist, or if you prefer, is $+\infty$.

Let $f_4(n)=\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^n$.
Then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} f_4(n)=0$.

Here is a slightly more complicated example. Let $f_5(n)=\left(1+\frac{\sin^2(\pi n/2)}{n}\right)^n$.

Then, for large $n$, $f_5(n)$ is bouncing around. Sometimes it is $1$, sometimes it is close to $e$.

We can produce examples that exhibit much weirder behaviour!

Answer (score 2):

It is defined. It's equal to $1$.