# Did anyone try to introduce $(-1)^\infty$ or $\sin \infty$ and $\cos \infty$ as numbers?

Tags: real-analysis

It seems to me that if we introduce such numbers, due to Fourier series we would be able to express the value of any periodic function at infinity as a trigonometric series of the above values.

It would be also possible to express the values of functions such as $\cos 1/x$ at zero, making them continuous.

For instance, if we define $w=(-1)^\infty$ then $\cos^2(\infty)=(w+\frac1w)/2+1/2$

We also would possibly be able to assign precise values to the series like $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k$

Comment: Sometimes it happens that putting together a bunch of things that don't make sense separately, you can get a consistent new interesting theory. I doubt that this is the case here.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378041/why-is-1-raised-to-infinity-not-defined-and-not-1/378054).

Comment: @Dietrich Burde this is a question about algebra, I know what is indeterminate form!

Comment: The answers there say that indeed people tried to introduce $\sin(\infty)$ as numbers, *however* ....I think there are many helpful answers which go much further than "indeterminate form" and also answer this question.

Comment: Why would being able to express the value of periodic functions at infinity or having $y=\cos\frac1x$ being continuous at $0$ be useful to mathematicians?  This seems like a solution in search of a problem.

Comment: @Matthew Daly well I do not claim it would be useful, I just wonder what would happen and what algebraic properties such a number would have.

Answer (score 1):

$(-1)^n$ alternates between 1 and -1 and so thinking about $(-1)^{\infty}$ doesn't really make sense. Similarly sine and cosine are oscillating waves that do not tend towards a fixed value in the real line. 
A Fourier series is an expansion of a periodic function in terms of an infinite sum of sines and cosines. The sum is infinite, not the arguments of the cosine and sine functions.

Comment: I was talking not about assigning a real value but a special value that is not a real number.

Comment: There's is no "symbol" that I'm aware of that represents these values, but the point is that these values are undetermined.

Comment: The 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 .. series also diverges, alternates b/w 0 and 1 but we have assigned a value of +1/2 to it. It seems like this should be possible.