# How to evaluate indeterminate form of a limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I can't evaluate indeterminate form of a limit like this:
$$\lim \limits_{x\to \infty} \left (\frac {x-1}{x+4}\right)^{3x+2}$$
I tried to solve this problem by multiplying fractions' top and bottom by the conjugate of the denominator. I did it many times but I don't have any success and I even don't know if this way right or wrong.

How this limit can be solved?

Comment: Do you know that $\left (\dfrac {x-1}{x+4}\right)^{3x+2}$ is short for something else?

Comment: Hint: ${x-1\over x+4}=1-{5\over x+4}$.

Comment: Thank you very much guys! You helped me a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will be easier to rewrite this limit in the form:
$$ \lim_{x} \left( \frac{1-1/x}{1+4/x} \right)^{3x+2}. $$
Now, it will suffice to learn how to compute limits of the form:
$$ \lim_{x} (1+a/x)^x.$$
This is not very difficult. You can show, for example, that $\ln(1+a/x) = a/x + O(1/x^2)$, so $1+a/x = e^{a/x + O(1/x^2)}$, and finally $(1+a/x)^x = e^{a+O(1/x)}$. Therefore, $\lim_{x} (1+a/x)^x = e^a$. Applying this in the limit you want to compute, we get:

$$\lim_{x} \left( \frac{1-1/x}{1+4/x} \right)^{3x+2} = \left(\frac{e^{-1}}{e^4}\right)^3= 1/e^{15}$$.

---

Note that the ["big O"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) notation was used. Vaguely speaking, $O(1/x^2)$ stands for a function that tends to $0$ at least as fast as $1/x^2$ does for $x \to \infty$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint :**
Given limit is of the form  $ 1^\infty $, It's a indeterminate form.
You can have a look of this to find the limit in such cases.

[Why is $1^{\infty}$ considered to be an indeterminate form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10490/why-is-1-infty-considered-to-be-an-indeterminate-form)

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left({x-1\over x + 4}\right)^{3x + 2}= 
\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(1 - {5\over x +4}\right)^{3x} \left(1 - {5\over x +4}\right)^2$$

The second factor goes to 1 at \infty, so what we have left is

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(1 - {5\over x +4}\right)^{3x}.$$
This last limit converges $e^{-15}.$