# Calculus (Infinity)

Tags: calculus

If we multiply 1 by itself any number of times then we get 1 but if we consider 1 raised to the power infinity then it's undefined. This has baffled me and I am unable to understand this case even I know that infinity is not a number. I need a satisfactory answer.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10490/why-is-1-infty-considered-to-be-an-indeterminate-form There are some detailed answers here.

Answer (score 0):

You have answered your own question. Infinity is not just a number. So raising 1 to power infinity doesnt make sense(it is undefined). If it does, then you might as well raise 1 to power "house" or "car" or anything. That is the meaning of undefined. However, $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}1^n=1.$

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are misremembering the statement that $1^\infty$ is an indeterminate form.  That is, from *only* the information
$$
\lim_{t \to a} f(t) = 1,\qquad\text{and}\qquad \lim_{t \to a} g(t) = \infty
$$
it is not possible to determine
$$
\lim_{t \to a} f(t)^{g(t)} .
$$

For example,
$$
\lim_{t \to 0} (1+t^2) = 1,
\qquad
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{t^2} = \infty
\qquad
\lim_{t \to 0} (1+t^2)^{1/t^2} = e
\\
\lim_{t \to 0} (1+t) = 1,
\qquad
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{t^2} = \infty
\qquad
\lim_{t \to 0} (1+t)^{1/t^2} = \infty
\\
\lim_{t \to 0} (1+t^2) = 1,
\qquad
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{t} = \infty
\qquad
\lim_{t \to 0} (1+t^2)^{1/t} = 1
$$

Comment: It is not entirely clear that the OP was asking about this.