# Why is $\lim_{x \to 0} x = (1+\tan x)^\frac{1}{x}$ not 1?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, exponential-function

Why is it wrong to think that $$\lim_{x \to 0} (1+\tan x)^\frac{1}{x} = (1+0)^\frac{1}{x}=1^\infty=1$$ because $\lim_{x \to 0} \tan x$ and $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x}=\infty$?
I already know the correct answer but could not figure out why this way is not correct.

Comment: Related: ["Why is $1^\infty$ considered to be an indeterminate form?"](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/10490/409)

Comment: it's the 1/x that is the indeterminate form, what you have is a limit where the exponent is tending towards infinity, but the case where (1 + 0) is multiplied by itself infinite times never actually happens, because x = 0 can never happen in that equation - if you consider (1 + ax) ^(1/x) your method of 1^infinity goes wrong - try it!

Answer (score 0):

$1^\infty$ is [indeterminate form](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Indeterminate_form), you can't say it is $1$.

Comment: I'd say it is the 1/x that is the indeterminate form, you can never plug zero into it.  Because you can't ever put zero into your 1/x, you never get (1 + 0) to raise to a power - you always have (1 + something)^(something massive).  But as far as I can see 1^x = 1 as x tends to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to "split up" the limit taking procedure. In your case you to take the limit of the base which is $1$ and you then want to take the limit of the exponent, which you say is $\infty$.
You are probably familiar with this precedure from expressions like these:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \to 0} (f(x) \cdot g(x)) = (\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)) \cdot (\lim_{x \to 0} g(x))
\end{equation}

Recall however that this **only** has to work when both limits of $f$ and $g$ **exist** as **real numbers**.
The very same splitting will usually work for most "nice" operations, like in your case exponentiation. (If you hit the limit $0^0$ however, it will not!)

But since $\infty$ is **not a real number**, it is (here) just a symbol denoting unbounded sequences, there is no reason the splitting should work.
$1^{\mathrm{bla}}$ when bla is no real number does not really make any sense at all.