# Why : $1^{+\infty}$ is not $1 $ however $1^{+\infty}=\lim _{x\to 0+}(\frac{\sin x}{x})^{1/x}=1$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, proof-verification

It is well known that :$1^{+\infty}$ is indeterminate case ,I have accrossed the following problem which let me  to say that :$1^{+\infty}=1$ .

$1^{+\infty}$ can be written as : $1^{+\infty}=\lim _{x\to 0+}(\frac{\sin x}{x})^{1/x}$ which is $ 1$  ,then $1^{+\infty}=1$ and it's not I.case , i don't know where i'm wrong !!!! ? and [wolfram alpha says that](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+((sinx%2Fx)%5E(1%2Fx)),+x+to+0%2B) :$\lim _{x\to 0+}(\frac{\sin x}{x})^{1/x}=1$ which mixed me .

**Edit:** I have edited the question to show what's mixed me in the side of 
limit calculation and i don't changed my question

Comment: If $a_n\to 1$ and $b_n\to\infty$ then $a_n^{b_n}$ may tend to $1$, or may tend to another positive number, or may diverge...

Comment: "indeterminate" means can not be consistently determined.  Determining something in one particular way is not determining it consistently in all possible possible ways.  So *one* interpretation does not contradict indeterminacy.

Comment: But honestly, I'm not seeing why $1^{\infty}$ which I would define as $\lim_{x\to \infty} 1^x$ should be indeterminate at all.  So what if $\lim_{y\to 1;x\to \infty} y^x$ is indeterminate.  We don't claim $f(a)$ is indeterminate if $f$ is discontinuous at $a$ if it's perfectly well defined.  We don't claim $f(a)$ must always equal $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ so why should we care about any limits as $y\to 1$?  Am I mistaken that $f(\infty)$ should be defined as $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$?

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main
page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730)
for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think that
$$\lim _{x\to 0^+}\bigg(\frac{\sin x}{x}\bigg)^{1/x} = \bigg(\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{\sin x}{x}\bigg)^{\lim_{x \to 0^+}1/x}$$
that is not correct. Here, you can find your answer I think: [Why is $1^{\infty}$ considered to be an indeterminate form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10490/why-is-1-infty-considered-to-be-an-indeterminate-form)

Answer (score 2):

What do you think of $$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x?$$

Answer (score 0):

Indeterminate means we can not assign a single real number to it without causing contradiction

In your question, different examples provide different answers such as $1$ or $e$ , hence the determination is not possible without contradiction.

Comment: $1^x=1$ for any $x\in R$ so $\lim 1^x=1$ as $x$ tends to $\infty$. But if $lim f(x)^{g(x)}=1^{\infty}$ as $x$ tends to $\infty$($f(x)$ is not constant) is an indeterminate case.

Comment: Good point for the case of base =1.