# Infinite indetermination

Tags: calculus, limits

Since $1^\infty$ results in indetermination ,does $2^\infty$ result in the same?

(I think I'm basically asking if $b^\infty$, with $b \in \mathbb{R} $, results in indetermination)

And why is the result of a limit in the form $1^\infty$ an indetermination?

Thank you!

Comment: No, $2^\infty$ is clearly infinity, nothing indeterminate about that. For $1^\infty$, see this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10490/why-is-1-infty-considered-to-be-an-indeterminate-form?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2^{+\infty}=e^{+\infty\ln (2)}=$$
$$=e^{+\infty}=+\infty $$

It is not indeterminate.

It is $+\infty $ because $\ln (2)>0$.

Comment: Just to make it clear: this is not an actual computation since the first step has no meaning.